# Plotting 3-vectors over a 3D lattice

Tags: graphics, vector

I am trying to plot a magnetic structure, which is basically using *Mathematica* to read and plot a .dat file. In the file, each row which has six numbers, the first 3 represents the atomic postion, and the last 3 number represents the 3 vector components (Sx, Sy, Sz). The final picture is a bunch of vectors in 3D space. Because I have hundreds of rows to plot, I need a programmatic way to do this. Does any one know how to do it?

An example of the data is as follows:

1   1   1   0.7504765036    -0.593865983    -0.290014158

---

1   0   0   -0.9292367337   0.1725123202    0.3267393337

---

0   1   0   0.8097462389    -0.1152598183   -0.5753487662

---

0   0   1   -0.9612643232   -0.1938986552   0.1958933701

---

1   3   3   -0.9621315393   0.2329016775    0.1416323044

---

1   2   2   -0.04878853791  0.2677151765    -0.9622620552

---

0   3   2   0.2802208194    -0.07621023259  -0.956905582

---

0   2   3   -0.04513399615  0.08166879923   0.9956370471

---

3   1   3   0.7531075402    0.1735299814    -0.6345993843

---

[image]

The final picuture should be something like this:

Comment: The meaning of the data entries isn't explained, and it's not clear which part of the *Mathematica* implementation your'e having trouble with, or which parts of the documentation are not sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = Table[RandomReal[], {100}, {6}];

myPts = 
  Graphics3D[
  {Red,
   PointSize[0.02],
   Point[
    data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]]
    ]}
  ];

myArrows = 
   Graphics3D[
   Arrow[Transpose@{data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], data[[All, {4, 5, 6}]]}]];

Show[myPts, myArrows]
```

[image]